# file_get_contents failing when was working earlier

Tags: php, api, http-headers

I am trying to access multiple json files provided by steam for the market price of an item for CSGO. I am using a first file_get_contents which works:

```
$inventory = file_get_contents('http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/' . $steamprofile['steamid'] . '/inventory/json/730/2');
```

but the 2nd onwards doesn't work:

```
$marketString = file_get_contents('http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?currency=1&appid=730&market_hash_name=' . urlencode($json_a->{'rgDescriptions'}->$rgDescrId->{'market_hash_name'}));
```

However I get the error on all items for example:

> Warning: file_get_contents(http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?currency=1&appid=730&market_hash_name=Negev%20|%20Nuclear%20Waste%20(Minimal%20Wear)): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 429 Unknown in /home4/matt500b/public_html/themooliecommunity.com/CSGO/index.php on line 24

**I can confirm that allow_url_fopen is on**

Pasting the following url into a browser shows that the url works

http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?currency=1&appid=730&market_hash_name=Negev%20|%20Nuclear%20Waste%20(Minimal%20Wear)

Please note that about 1 hour ago this worked but now throwing an error, any suggestions?

Comment: 429 Too Many Requests (RFC 6585)
    The user has sent too many requests in a given amount of time. Intended for use with rate limiting schemes.[57]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got response with status [429 Too many requests](https://httpstatuses.com/429)

> The user has sent too many requests in a given amount of time ("rate
>   limiting").

So this site can just block too frequent reference to his API

Answer (score 1):

A HTTP 429 is a too many request warning, it's not an error, just a note to tell you you've over done it a little. You'll have to either wait a while or if it's your own server then adjust it's settings to allow for more requests.